# Identification of protozoa under microscope

Tags: species-identification, microbiology, microscopy

I observed maybe Protozoa from standing FRESH water and from slowly flowing FRESH water. I am complete dilettante. Can you tell what these creatures are?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6D5ck3zNJzA&t=474s

Thank you.

Added picture for to be more specific

[image]

Comment: What level of magnification was employed within the video?

Comment: something around 200 I guess

Comment: Please put a snapshot of the organism that you want to identify, instead of linking to youtube.

Comment: I cut it from the video, it is not very good, but at least it is specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, the organisms may hold the appearance of protozoans like ciliates. However, I am of the belief that these 'totally tubular' micro organisms are in fact diatoms.

The diatoms are a diverse range of eucaryotic microalgae which comprise a large percentage of the phytoplankton group. (Diatomaceous earth is the residual remains of their calcareous walls)

They are likely diatoms because of their apparent hard membrane, and slight brown-green pigment, typical of heterokont diatoms.

I would be unable to specify the organism to family level. However, you may wish to complete your investigation by looking under the order 'Pennales'.

For general information regarding the Diatoms, you may visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatom
Morphology and description available from: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xhLJvNa3hw0C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Good luck

Comment: Ok, as noob I need explanation. You mean they are not Protozoan rather algae? And by "they" you mean those which are smaller, but there is plenty of them with "balls" at the end and at beginning and also in the middle of the cell?
(i hope someday make better video with known magnification).

Comment: I also asked my former biology teacher and she guessed "Diatomeae". Though I have to google it and translate it.

Comment: @weatherman It is likely that your teacher were indeed referring to the Diatom class. 'Diatomea' is deemed a synonym for the Diatom class Bacillariophyceae: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatom